# Check if title field has a string in ElementAPI

Tags: plugin-elementapi, plugin-craftcommerce2

I am trying to retrieve search suggestions for a search form. I sent the parameter entered by the user, but how do I do it in the criteria?
I tried this:

```
'criteria' => [
    'search' => 'title: *'.Craft::$app->request->getParam("key").'*'
],
```

but it does not return any results. What am I doing wrong?
this is my entire endpoint:

```
'suggests' =>function(){
        return [
            'elementType' => Product::class,
            'paginate' => false,
            'pretty' => true,
            'criteria' => [
                'limit' => 15,
                'search' => 'title: *'.Craft::$app->request->getParam("key").'*'
            ],
            'transformer' => function(Product $product)  {
                return [
                    'title' => $product->title,
                    'url' => $product->url
                ];
            },
        ];
    },
```

Comment: Got it. LOL 
'criteria' => [
                    'title' => '*'.Craft::$app->request->getParam("key").'*'
                ],
that was fast.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! Would you mind adding that as an official answer in case it ends up helping someone in the future?

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

```
'criteria' => [ 'title' => '*'.Craft::$app->request->getParam("key").'*' ]
```